# Let a view be a "window" to the background

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For the effect shown, I know a calculation must be made. Either the message bubble is a "hole" or "window" that exposes the background, where the background is the gradient shown, or the gradient is given in a bitmap, scaled to screen size, and each message bubbles's background is set to the portion of the bitmap represented by the location and boundary of the view. This will have to be updated for each view every time the recycler is scrolled (seems intensive).

This GIF shows the intended effect.

[image: Messages are a "window" to the background]

Notes:

I've concluded this effect can be simulated in a variety of ways, but I think the view being a "window" sounds more process effecient.

1. The app background is a purple-blue gradient, and the recycler background is white but transparent on the area of the messages, and the messages are transparent. This would mean the calculating happens in the recycler's OnScroll or onDraw and it updates it's own canvas or background. It would "erase" the part of the view covered by a message.
2. The app background is a purple-blue gradient and the recycler background is completely white. This would mean the calculating happens in the recycler's onScroll or onDraw and it updates each message's background. The background would be calculated using the position and height of the message, and the gradient given.
3. The app background is a gradient and there is some "AppBackgroundViewerView" somewhere on GitHub.

**The Issue**

1. This would be trivial if the app background was a solid color. I would simply make the background of the messages the same color. I would not need an "app background" at all.

*This is not the desired effect*
[image: Loading messages with solid background color]

2. I cannot achieve this effect by setting the background of each view to the app background. As you can see, the views toward the bottom of the screen are completely blue. If I set the background of the message to the app background (purple-blue gradient) then the messages at the bottom would also have purple in them. This is trivial and I wouldn't need an "app background" or reference image/gradient to calculate anything with.

*This is not the desired effect*
[image]

It is clear there must be some form of runtime calculation.

My only guess is to store the "app background" image as a bitmap and programmatically set the background of each message bubble to the portion of the bitmap that the message bubbles' location and bounds requires. This would not require a top level "app background"

For my particular layout, The activity root is a RelativeLayout. The root holds a RecyclerView, RecyclerView holds some MessageView.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 11/24/2020: Adding sample project link**

I put up a working example of the desired chat bubble effect. Please clone the following repository and pay special attention to the **ChatMessageView.kt** class. Let me know if you have any questions.

https://github.com/jetpack-toast/chat-with-background-revealing-bubbles

**PRE-EDIT**

The only way I can think of to get the desired effect with minimal impact on performance closely matches what you have in your first note from above:

> 1. The app background is a purple-blue gradient, and the recycler background is white but transparent on the area of the messages, and the messages are transparent. This would mean the calculating happens in the recycler's OnScroll or onDraw and it updates it's own canvas or background. It would "erase" the part of the view covered by a message.

Update your MessageView class to draw only the opaque portions of each message rather than the message bubble (all the white space). This should make any background show through just fine, but only on the message bubble portion. See the image below for a visual representation.

[what to draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Kpf.png)

Comment: I am having trouble finding out how to draw around the messageview. I can override OnDraw, but I do not know how to achieve drawing the whitespace and not the space the opaque parts occupy.

Comment: @HerbSmith The onDraw() method receives a Canvas object. The Canvas object contains methods which will allow you to draw lines, arcs, text, bitmaps, paths, etc. I'll code up a sample and put it here once I can get away from work.

Comment: @HerbSmith I just want you to know that I haven't forgotten about this. I have a nearly working demo that I'll put up on GitHub once it's ready. Should be ready this weekend.

Comment: @HerbSmith Was I able to help you get what you needed?